# How to use the requestJS get method to set the cookie？

Tags: javascript, cookies, request

```
    let headers = {
    'Accept': xxxxx,
    'Host': 'xxxx',
    'Referer': 'https://xxxx/',
  }
  request.get(url, {
    json: true,
    headers: headers
  }).on('response', function (response) {
    let headers = response.headers['set-cookie'];
  })
```

If I use

```
headers = {
 'Accept': xxx,
 'cookie':xxx
}
```

it will memory leak

Answer (score 1):

According to [the README of request](https://github.com/request/request#examples), you can use `request.jar()` to set your own cookie to the request.

```
var j = request.jar();
var cookie = request.cookie('key1=value1');
var url = 'http://www.google.com';
j.setCookie(cookie, url);
request({url: url, jar: j}, function () {
  request('http://images.google.com')
})
```

**UPDATE:**

They said,

> Cookies are disabled by default (else, they would be used in subsequent requests). To enable cookies, set jar to true (either in defaults or options).

So you can enable request to use cookies just to set `{ jar: true }`.

```
var request = request.defaults({jar: true})
request('http://www.google.com', function () {
  request('http://images.google.com')
})
```